# Index a key as a value in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jsonschema

I am trying to index JSON Schemas in ElasticSearch. JSON Schemas are usually composed of multiple parts called definitions. Here's an example:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "first_name": { "type": "string" },
        "last_name":           { "type": "string" },
      },
      "required": ["first_name", "last_name"]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to search for definitions and find "address" and "user".

Is there any way to define this in a mapping using basic ElasticSearch functionality? I've seen the Transform feature in X-Pack, but it is not well documented.

Comment: `Transform` feature using to change your payload data to prepare your data to watcher action part while the watcher trigger executing. Please add some more information and action list to tell us your aim. You can add a list to explain step by step of your problem.

Comment: @hkulekci, I finally moved to Lucene and used a suggester to define separately fields to search for and the payload.